# Way to give all the situtations in "case when" without list them in the query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do a "case when" block, however, there are many situations. Instead of listing all the possibilities, is there any other way? (And all these 3 fields' values are stored in my database)

[image]

For now what I did is this:

```
left join [RISK].[dbo].[FILiquidityBuckets] FB7
on FB7.Metric='Industry sector/Group'
and(((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Corporate' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Energy') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Corporate' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Financial') and FB7.LiquidityScore=2)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Corporate' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Infrastructure') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Corporate' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Communication') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Corporate' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Securitization') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Corporate' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Real Estate') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Corporate' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Industrial') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Provincial' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Ontario') and FB7.LiquidityScore=1)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Provincial' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Alberta') and FB7.LiquidityScore=2)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Federal' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Agency') and FB7.LiquidityScore=2)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Provincial' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='New Brunswick') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Provincial' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Newfoundland') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Provincial' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='British Columbia') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Federal' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Non-Agency') and FB7.LiquidityScore=1)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Municipal' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Ontario') and FB7.LiquidityScore=2)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Provincial' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Quebec') and FB7.LiquidityScore=1)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Provincial' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Saskatchewan') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Provincial' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Manitoba') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Municipal' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Manitoba') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Municipal' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='British Columbia') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Municipal' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup is Null) and FB7.LiquidityScore=4)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Municipal' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Quebec') and FB7.LiquidityScore=2)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Provincial' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Nova Scotia') and FB7.LiquidityScore=3)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Government' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Municipal' and sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup='Newfoundland') and FB7.LiquidityScore=4)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector='Preferred Equity' and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup='Preferred Equity') and FB7.LiquidityScore=2)
or
((sm.scotiaIndustrySector is null and sm.scotiaIndustryGroup is null) and FB7.LiquidityScore=5)
)
```

Please help thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new table to the database. It will look like this:

```
IndustrySector IndustryGroup  IndustrySubGroup  LiquidityScore
Corporate      Financial                              2
Corporate      Infrastructure                         3
Corporate      Communication                          3
Corporate      Securitization                         3
Corporate      Real Estate                            3
Corporate      Industrial                             3
Government     Provincial     Ontario                 1
Government     Provincial     Alberta                 2
Government     Federal        Agency                  2
Government     Provincial     New Brunswick           3
Government     Provincial     Newfoundland            3
Government     Provincial     British Columbia        3
Government     Federal        Non-Agency              1
Government     Municipal      Ontario                 2
Government     Provincial     Quebec                  1
Government     Provincial     Saskatchewan            3
```

This recreates the Excel sheet as an actual database table (I only took the time to re-type the items from the SQL, where I could copy/paste more. *Avoid using images in questions to present data!*) The blanks above are empty strings, rather than NULL, because of how `NULL=NULL` is false.

Using `LiquidityBucketGroups` as the name, you now can solve the issue with another JOIN:

```sql
LEFT JOIN [RISK].[dbo].[FILiquidityBuckets] FB7
    ON FB7.Metric='Industry sector/Group'
INNER JOIN [RISK].[dbo].[LiquidityBucketGroups] LG
    ON LG.IndustrySector = sm.scotiaIndustrySector 
        AND LG.IndustryGroup =  sm.scotiaIndustryGroup
        AND LG.IndustrySubGroup = sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup
        AND LG.LiquidityScore = FB7.LiquidityScore
```

You may want an additional column for the `Metric` field from the existing table. Also, if there's a potential for more than one match (seems unlikely for this case) you can use an `APPLY` or `WHERE EXISTS` instead of a join, and you may need to use a `COALESCE()` in the subgroup comparison, like this:  `LG.IndustrySubGroup=COALESCE(sm.scotiaIndustrySubGroup,'')`.

The best parts of this are you can have **indexes** on the new table, which can greatly aid performance, and you can easily adjust this table as business rules or scoring changes over time, without going back and re-writing the query.